# Application for watching online TV

Tags: software-recommendation, internet, tv

Is there a desktop application that is able to browse and play online TV channels (similar to browser extensions like chrome tv)?
I found democracy player, but there are no channels.
The application should support many channels from all over the world and be able to choose by categories or countries.

Answer (score 4):

The best player I've seen is **Miro** player. It can play from a lot of sources, torrents, podcasts and feeds. You can browse from thousands of chanels directly from Miro or from their website, so far all popular channels I've seen are there.

Watch their presentation at [getmiro.com](http://getmiro.com)

You can install it from the ubuntu software center.

good luck!

[image]

Comment: miro = democracyplayer

Comment: miro > democracyplayer  :P can you explain what you mean by "there are no channels"?

Comment: Look at [this](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_XYizHvjgLrA/Rd8s6znBfsI/AAAAAAAAAYE/DCy_qFLgt54/s1600/democracy-player-utube.jpg) picture. In the menu there is "channel" which is missing in miro. Miro is quite different in comparison to chrome tv.

Comment: @xralf there are channels in Miro...

Answer (score 2):

Sopcast is the tool for watching TV online for free. This software is assessed that it can download video quickly and pick up some radio stations. However, novice users may feel like a fish out of water. The following tutorial will help users watch TV on Sopcast easily.

How to watch TV with Sopcast : http://tips.betdownload.com/how-to-watch-tv-with-sopcast-8n.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To some extent it depends where you are in the world...e.g. Zattoo will work in some countries in Europe.

There's

- **Zattoo** http://zattoo.com/download
- **Livestation** http://www.livestation.com/downloads
- **FreetuxTV** http://www.tomsguide.com/us/download/freetuxtv,0301-35068.html
- **MarTV** http://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=en&sl=es&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fubuntulife.wordpress.com%2F2010%2F06%2F08%2Fmartv-radio-y-tv-online-en-ubuntu%2F&anno=2
- **Sopcast Player** (mentioned above) http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Internet-Radio-TV-Player/SopCast.shtml
- **TVCatchup** (available in the UK) http://www.tvcatchup.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is an application called sopcast, but it is a bit of trouble to set up. I also unfortunately do not have instructions off hand (as I removed it from my system).

Answer (score 0):

There's also gPodder (best obtained from the [gPodder PPA](https://launchpad.net/~thp/+archive/gpodder)) in connection with [gpodder.net](http://gpodder.net). I have used miro for a while and in the end abandoned it because it was simply too slow. gPodder is for feeds only though, so no streams here.